# Select all indexes from database system table, aggregate data based on the index in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, group-by, system

I'm using Oracle as database for a CRM.

I was requested to generate a complete list of indexes based on certain condition for the table names to be checked.

I've found and elaborated the following query:

```
select ind.index_name,
       ind_col.column_name,
       tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT,
       ind.table_name
from sys.all_indexes ind
         inner join sys.all_ind_columns ind_col on
            ind.owner = ind_col.index_owner and ind.index_name = ind_col.index_name
         left outer join sys.all_TAB_COLS tab_cols on
            ind_col.COLUMN_NAME = tab_cols.COLUMN_NAME and
            INDEX_TYPE='FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL' and
            tab_cols.OWNER = ind.owner and
            ind_col.COLUMN_NAME like 'SYS_NC%' and
            tab_cols.TABLE_NAME = ind.table_name
where  [requested conditions]
order by ind.table_name,INDEX_NAME;
```

This query is generating something like 1.600 rows, most of them are repeated values of INDEX_NAME, since if the index has more than one parameter, I've the field repeated.

What I want to do is the following:

1. Group all the values of one index as defined inside ind_col.column_name inside one single column, comma separated
2. (if possible) have the value of tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT (long) instead of ind_col.column_name in case the first value is not null.

Can I have you help about this?

Thanks a lot for any reply!

Comment: Have a look at ```LISTAGG``` for a comma separated list and ```NVL```or  ```NVL2``` to handle a NULL/NOT NULL value

Comment: DATA_DEFAULT is not a CLOB but a LONG unfortunately, which is very, very hard to savely convert to VARCHAR2. I ended up with a database failure "SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2147, context 0:0:0 unsafe to proceed" on my DBMS (Oracle 19c Enterprise  Edition).

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.listagg can be used on the columns you want to aggregate:

''' 
select substr(sys.listagg(ind.index_name||','),1,length(sys.listagg(ind.index_name||',')-1))   as index_name,
       ind_col.column_name,
       tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT,
       ind.table_name
from sys.all_indexes ind
inner join sys.all_ind_columns ind_col on
    ind.owner = ind_col.index_owner and ind.index_name = ind_col.index_name
left outer join sys.DBA_TAB_COLS tab_cols on
    ind_col.COLUMN_NAME = tab_cols.COLUMN_NAME
    and INDEX_TYPE='FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL'
    and tab_cols.OWNER = ind.owner and ind_col.COLUMN_NAME like 'SYS_NC%'
where [list of custom conditions]
group by 
  ind_col.column_name,`enter code here`
       tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT,
       ind.table_name
order by INDEX_NAME;
`enter code here`
'''
```

Comment: Did you actually try it? What result did you get?

Comment: Unofrtunately, this is working partially, since I'm still getting ORA-00997 using tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT since it's a long type

Comment: If possible, please exclude data_fault column. If not, the workaround is to use :
substr(to_char(tab_cols.DATA_DEFAULT),1,4000). If the value of data_default is longer, the only first  4000 characters will be used.
.

Comment: @little_amb I've already to try that, I've at the moment used excel to group data... In any case, I don't think it's possible to exclude that field, if I want the data of formulas displayed inside the query

Comment: @little_amb I've tried the conversion suggested and it's returning an Oracle error.

Answer (score 0):

This is how far I got. I ended up with a database failure "SP2-0642: SQL*Plus internal error state 2147, context 0:0:0 unsafe to proceed" on my DBMS (Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition). Maybe it helps somehow, nonetheless.

```
with
  function get_data_default(
    p_owner varchar2,
    p_table_name varchar2,
    p_column_name varchar2,
    p_index_type varchar2) return varchar2
  as
    v_long long;
  begin
    select data_default
    into v_long
    from dba_tab_cols
    where owner = p_owner
    and table_name = p_table_name
    and column_name = p_column_name
    and p_index_type = 'FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL'
    and column_name like 'SYS_NC%';
    
    return substr(v_long, 1, 4000);
  end get_data_default;
select 
  ind.owner,
  ind.index_name,
  listagg(
    coalesce(
      get_data_default(ind.table_owner, ind.table_name, ind_col.column_name, ind.index_type),
      ind_col.column_name), ', ') 
    within group (order by ind_col.column_position) as cols,
  ind.table_name
from dba_indexes ind
inner join dba_ind_columns ind_col on ind.owner = ind_col.index_owner
                                  and ind.index_name = ind_col.index_name
where [list of custom conditions]
group by ind.owner, ind.index_name, ind.table_name
order by ind.owner, ind.index_name, ind.table_name;
```

(In case you wonder why ind.table_name is in the `GROUP BY` clause in spite of having grouped by index owner and name aready: Oracle requires this, because the DBMS is not able to detect functional dependencies in `GROUP BY`, yet.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let's hope someone will take the work from here on :)
Unfortunately I'm pretty new with Oracle, SQL and sys tables (and idexes too)

Comment: Otherwise, is there someplace else where I can get the values of the SYS_NC fields?